# Regex to match multiple words separated by commas and quotation marks

Tags: regex

Test string:
`tags = ["#scRNA-seq", "#single_cell", "#NGS", "#single_cell:method"]`

Goal: Remove brackets, quotes and commas.

Desired output:

`tags = #scRNA-seq #single_cell #NGS #single_cell:method`

My attempt:
https://regex101.com/r/b18o27/1

I can match the first term, but I don't know how to match every single term.

Comment: Try `[\[\]",]` https://regex101.com/r/ymv31D/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just strip the unwanted characters to clean your string. This is much easier than capturing the whole structure and detecting the correct parts to keep within it.

**Regular Expression**

```
~[",\[\]]~
```

**Replacement Pattern**

```
~~
```

Example:

```
IN  -> tags = ["#scRNA-seq", "#single_cell", "#NGS", "#single_cell:method"]
OUT -> tags = [#scRNA-seq #single_cell #NGS #single_cell:method]
```

You can try a working demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/4iXlOU/1).